# Show that if a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then the function $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $T(x)=Ax$ is continuous.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

**Conjecture**: If a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then the function $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $T(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}$ is continuous in the metric space induced by the $2$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**My Question**: Can any one please tell me if the conjecture is true or false? I failed to prove the conjecture, but I couldn't find a counterexample either. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Linear maps are always continuous, invertible or not.

Comment: @Randall Thank you so much for the confirmation! This answered my question.

Comment: You can search about "operator norm" and "singular value decomposition".

Comment: @DickGrayson You can show that $\|Ax - Ay\| \leq c\|x-y\|,$ where $c > 0$ is a constant that depends solely on $A.$ A choice like $c = \sum_{i,j} |a_{i,j}|$ or $c = nm \max_{i,j} \|a_{i,j}|$ tend to work easily.